# Drive Realtime API throwing errors every 60s

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

Every 55 seconds or so, the Drive Realtime API javascript throws a `TypeError`. Everything actually seems to keep working, but it's driving my automatic error logging totally insane, and of course it worries me to just be getting unexplainable errors all the time for all of my users.

[image]

You can see the error in action at https://peardeck.com/editor/?state=%7B%22action%22%3A%22create%22%7D if you're willing to install our app. Just wait 60 seconds and you'll see the error appear from drive.google.com/otservice/api .

We've narrowed this all the way down in our testing scaffold - we stripped out all code after the initial opening of the realtime document, and still this happens every minute or so. The errors happen at the same time that the script seems to be trying to switch between long-polling get requests:

[image: network timeline matches timing of errors]

I'm not actually sure how long this has been going on. Does anyone from the realtime team have any thoughts? Has anyone else noticed this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

We've been told that a fix for this is coming soon. Also it does not look like this is causing problems